# Swiper JS - Lazyload not working on duplicate slides for looping slide

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to use Swiper JS and its native lazy loading params but it's not working on duplicate or cloned slides. Here's an exemple :

```
var lazyLoadImages = new LazyLoad({
        elements_selector: ".lazy",
    });

    const swiper3 = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        loop: true,
        slidePerView: 1,
        lazy: true,

        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true
        },

        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-unique',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-unique',
        },
        preloadImages: true
    });

    if (lazyLoadImages) {
        lazyLoadImages.update();
    }
```

Comment: Please make a snippet rather than writing your code via snippet tool

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.